# Trying to filter results, none is displayed

Tags: php, filter

I am trying to filter results from a database. I have a class Filter which is as follows

```
<?php

class Filter{
    protected $_dbHandle, $_dbInstance;
    function search_car()
    {

        $this->_dbInstance = Database::getInstance();
        $this->_dbHandle = $this->_dbInstance->getdbConnection();

        $by_type = $_POST['by_type'];
        $by_make = $_POST['by_make'];
        $by_price = $_POST['by_price'];
        $by_year_of_registration = $_POST['by_year_of_registration'];

        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE";
        if ($by_type != "") {
            $sql_query .= " type='$by_type'";
        }
        if ($by_make != "") {
            $sql_query .= " make='$by_make'";
        }
        if ($by_price != "") {
            $sql_query .= " price='$by_price'";
        }
        if ($by_year_of_registration != "") {
            $sql_query .= " year_of_registration='$by_year_of_registration'";
        }
        $statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sql_query); // prepare a PDO statement
        $statement->execute(); // execute the PDO statement


            return $statement;
        }

}`
```

And the call to this class is here:

```
    <?php if(isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
    $filter = new Filter;
    $retrieved_result = $filter->search_car($_POST);
$row = $retrieved_result->fetch();
$carData1 = new CarData($row);
foreach ($carData1 as $carData) {
    echo '<tr> <td>' . $carData->getType() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getMake() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getModel() . '</td>
              <td>' . $carData->getColour() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getPrice() . '</td> <td>' . $carData->getYearOfRegistration() . '</td>
              <td>' . $carData->getPicture() . '</td><td></tr>';
}
}
?>
```

I have tried to place the echo inside the filter class but nothing changed. The output is.. None. The place where the result should be stays empty, but all the other content is on the page. How should I proceed now ? What should I do ?

Comment: "Nothing is displayed on the page." Turn on error reporting and check your logs.

Comment: I mean the result is not displayed on the page, the other content is there. I have all my records from the database shown above the result area, but where the result should be stays empty. I will edit my question now.

Comment: Do what Chris said, also, what does `var_dump($retrieved_result);` return? just before your `$row = ...`

Comment: `object(PDOStatement)[8]
  public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM **** WHERE type='sports'' (length=45)` is what the var_dump gives me.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple issues here, the first is your resulting query is likely wrong. Consider this `$_POST` data:

```
$_POST = [
    'by_type' => 'minivan',
    'by_year_of_registration' => '2011'
]
```

Your resulting SQL will look like:

```
SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE type='minivan' year_of_registration='2011'
```

You are missing an `AND` conditional here.

You can figure this out by `var_dump()`ing `$sql_query`, and also you need to check your return values on `$statement->execute()` (it should be returning `false`).

You can fix this by putting the `WHERE` clauses in an array, and `implode(' AND ', $where)`

**Additionally** you have a SQL injection vulnerability here, imagine a `$_POST` like so:

```
$_POST = [
    'by_type' => '\' OR is_hidden=1'
]
```

Now your SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE type='' OR is_hidden=1
```

Obviously that example is probably innocuous, but it could also be damaging SQL. The solution to this is to a) filter input, and b) use prepared queries *correctly*, this will escape the values:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE ";
$where = array();
$values = array();
if ($by_type != "") {
    $where[] = "type = :type";
    $values[':type'] = $by_type;
}
if ($by_make != "") {
    $where[] = "make = :make";
    $values[':make'] = $by_make;
}
if ($by_price != "") {
    $where[] = "price = :price";
    $values[':price'] = $by_price;
}
if ($by_year_of_registration != "") {
    $where[] = "year_of_registration = :year";
    $values[':year'] = $by_year_of_registration;
}

$sql_query .= implode(' AND ', $where);

$statement = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($sql_query); // prepare the query
$result = $statement->execute($values); // Pass in the values

if (!$result || $statement->rowCount() == 0) {
    // query failed (invalid query, or no results)
} else {
    // we have results
}
```

(You might also put these filter option names in an array and foreach over them checking $_POST, and constructing the `$where` and `$values` that way, rather than linearly like this)

Comment: trying this ends up with this error: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound `  How should I proceed ?

Comment: What is your resulting SQL? `var_dump($sql_query)`, it sounds like you forgot to concat the implode, maybe?

Comment: `string 'SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE type=:type' (length=42)` or `string 'SELECT * FROM sta402_cars WHERE type=:type AND price=:price' (length=59)` if I try to have more than 1 filter

Comment: And you are passing `$values` into `$statement->execute()`?

Comment: Ah, i was just executing the query 2 times, after fixing this the error went away but now this one appeared: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in /home/sta402/PHP_stuff/CarTemplate/Views/CarList.phtml on line 55` concerning this code : `$filter = new Filter;
    $retrieved_result = $filter->search_car($_POST);
    $row = $retrieved_result->fetch();`

Comment: What are you returning?

Comment: Was retuning $result, changed it to $statement. The error is gone, but still no output is shown to the page. If I do the var_dump it gives me all the separate entries column by column but its not letting them through the echo. No errors shown at this stage.

Comment: Two issues, you need to loop, like: foreach ($retrieved_result as $result) { $car = new CarData($result); } and the second issue that I have no idea what your CarData class looks like, you'll want to start putting strategic `var_dump()`'s inside your object and see what's going on.